# Backing up Nokia 6300 phone

Tags: backup

Nokia's own Ovi Suite is glittering piece of designer's wet dream - full of custom widgets, animated logos, sliding screens and zero functionality. After banging my head on famous "suite is busy" message while trying to make it run backup tool I simply give up. My previous experience with less overweight version of this software also tells me that resulting backup is a single big file with no good tools to easily read separate elements inside it.

So, question is, is there 3rd party tool, preferably free and open to back up Nokia 6300 phone?

Poking around the web, it seems that there could be at least somewhat standartised interface to access contact/message/whatever phone data for different phones, so if that tool could serve other brand phones - even better.

Another very important feature that I'd be happy to have in such tool if it would back up contact and messages in some human-readable way (CSV, JSON, XML, whatever) or at least in some common format. Even better if it would split messages in separate files ala [maildir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/maildir). Being able to "move" content to backup, deleting it from phone after backup is done wouldn't hurt too.

Any information on libraries with bindings to dynamic languages is welcome as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Nokia PC Suite](http://europe.nokia.com/support/product-support/pc-suites/compatibility-and-download?#131)(instead of Ovi Suite) to back up the stuff in your mobile, unfortunately not in human readable form.

It is a lot less cluttered and has better functionality.

You can use [Noki](http://europe.nokia.com/support/product-support/pc-suites/compatibility-and-download?#131) to read .nbu's

> Noki is a utility to explore and extract Phone book, Text message, MMS, Calendar, Memo, Email,  Bookmark and other user files from the backup file of Nokia phone (using  Nokia PC Suite).

Comment: Yes, I've mentioned that I've used older versions. Indeed PC Suite is much less cluttered with useless bells and whistles, but one monolithic .nbu backup is still unwieldy.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov There is no other solution, I was searching for this a long time ago, never found a solution. Let's see if anyone else knows something else. See the edit, there is Noki

Comment: Yes, know about Noki too. Too bad that it can't export all this mess to some more accessible format, so I'd have choice of software to view/search/otherwise process data.

Comment: The Noki link leads to the [Nokia PC Suite URL](http://www.nokia.com/global/support/product/nokia-pc-suite/?#131) too.